# Delete from DB in Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I want to delete a row in DB and it works but here is the problem:

- If I enter the value that exists in DB, it is deleted and I get a message "Your Booking is successful canceled"
- But also if I enter the value that not exists in DB, I get the same message. Why if the condition does not work?

  ```
    String sql = "delete from vaccines.patients where idNum = ?";
    String res = "Your Booking is successfully canceled";
    PreparedStatement state;

    try {
        state = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        state.setString(1, member.getIdNum());
        if (member.getIdNum().equals(null)) {
            res = "Enter id";
        }

        state.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        res="Your Booking is not successfully canceled";
    }
  ```

Comment: The delete statement succeeds whether or not it manages to update any rows. It is not an error to have a where clause on a delete statement which matches nothing.  Look at the Javadoc for PreparedStatement.executeUpdate and notice its return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check the number of affected rows instead since an update statement not affecting any rows won't error out.

e.g.

```
int rowCount = state.executeUpdate();

if (rowCount == 0) {
    throw ...;
}
```